# failed to initialize the k8s master

Tags: kubernetes

hello I'm new to K8s and trying to install a K8S master.
I've settled up Containerd runtime according to :
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd

and systemd as the cgroup driver

```
 [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]

    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
     ...
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
           SystemdCgroup = true
```

here's 10-kubeadm.conf:

```
root@k8s-master:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd --container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock"
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"#Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

while I try to initialize using the bellowing command , 172.21.103.8 is the ip of the master node:

```
kubeadm init  --apiserver-advertise-address 172.21.103.8 --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --image-repository registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers --v=9
```

in the output, there repeating connection refused

```
I1008 04:31:43.258402    3991 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.25.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/5835544" 'https://172.21.103.8:6443/healthz?timeout=10s'
I1008 04:31:43.258613    3991 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:172.21.103.8:6443 failed: dial tcp 172.21.103.8:6443: connect: connection refused
I1008 04:31:43.258659    3991 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.21.103.8:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I1008 04:31:43.258671    3991 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1008 04:31:43.258681    3991 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I1008 04:31:43.759012    3991 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.25.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/5835544" -H "Accept: application/json, */*" 'https://172.21.103.8:6443/healthz?timeout=10s'
I1008 04:31:43.759282    3991 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:172.21.103.8:6443 failed: dial tcp 172.21.103.8:6443: connect: connection refused
I1008 04:31:43.759323    3991 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.21.103.8:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I1008 04:31:43.759337    3991 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1008 04:31:43.759347    3991 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I1008 04:31:44.259098    3991 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.25.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/5835544" 'https://172.21.103.8:6443/healthz?timeout=10s'
I1008 04:31:44.259392    3991 round_trippers.go:508] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:172.21.103.8:6443 failed: dial tcp 172.21.103.8:6443: connect: connection refused
I1008 04:31:44.259438    3991 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.21.103.8:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I1008 04:31:44.259459    3991 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 0 ms
I1008 04:31:44.259474    3991 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
```

while checking the Kubelet service which is abnormal

```
root@k8s-master:/etc/kubernetes# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-10-08 04:34:48 UTC; 20ms ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
    Process: 4613 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 4613 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

root@k8s-master:/etc/kubernetes# journalctl -f -u kubelet
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master kubelet[4402]: Flag --container-runtime has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.27 as the only valid value is 'remote'
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master kubelet[4402]: Flag --container-runtime has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.27 as the only valid value is 'remote'
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master kubelet[4402]: Flag --pod-infra-container-image has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.27. Image garbage collector will get sandbox image information from CRI.
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master kubelet[4402]: I1008 04:33:36.897682    4402 server.go:200] "--pod-infra-container-image will not be pruned by the image garbage collector in kubelet and should also be set in the remote runtime"
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master kubelet[4402]: I1008 04:33:36.905173    4402 server.go:413] "Kubelet version" kubeletVersion="v1.25.2"
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master kubelet[4402]: I1008 04:33:36.905454    4402 server.go:415] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master kubelet[4402]: E1008 04:33:36.906132    4402 run.go:74] "command failed" err="failed to run Kubelet: unable to load bootstrap kubeconfig: stat /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf: no such file or directory"
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 08 04:33:36 k8s-master systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

can anyone help? any suggestion would be appreciate

thanks,
YF

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your /etc/containerd/config.toml to the next:

```
version = 2
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
  runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
    SystemdCgroup = true
```